# Redirect loop between htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my folder structure:

```
---- downloads
    ---- .htaccess
    ---- index.php
    ---- download 1
    ---- download 2
    ---- download n
```

.htaccess contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

index.php contents:

```
<?php
// do stuff

header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

---

I'm redirecting every request for a download, e.g. `downloads/download 1` to `index.php` where I do something and then redirect to the original file, `downloads/download 1`.

This works out fine except that I don't know how to NOT apply the rewrite rule in `.htaccess` when the HTTP referrer is `index.php`.
I tried with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*index\.php$ [NC]` but it keeps looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the HTTP referrer does not end with `index.php`

```
!^.*index\.php$
```

you do the redirect. In your question however you've said, that the referrers ends with `downloads/download 1`.

The `HTTP_REFERER` is set by your browser. And your browser will not update the URL.

Next to that, even if your browser would have done, the URL would still not end with `index.php` but with `index.php?uid=downloads%2Fdownload%201`.

So you have to re-think how you would like to check for the referrer and how you update the referrer as well. Maybe using a redirect helps with that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*index\.php.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?uid=$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: The browser still gives a "The page isn't redirecting properly" page. What about sending an URL with a GET variable back via PHP, like `/downloads/download 1?referred=1`. Would that work and how would I check for that one instead of the HTTP referer in the htaccess file?

Comment: Ensure that you're not using a firewall/browser, that removes all `HTTP_REFERER` header for privacy settings. The added query parameter would be easier to check, you can do this with `RewriteCond` or `RewriteRule`.